# How to remove unnecessary css when it compiled to output in TailwindCSS?

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm combining tailwindcss with another ui framework (Ant Design), but having some conflicts with the css in tailwind.
I want to compile the necessary classnames if it is used to minimize conflicts

My expect example:

```
<div className="text-center font-bold" />
```

After compiled in output.css file:

```
.text-center { 
  text-align: center;
}
.font-bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

which this output results should not included css default like:

```
html{-moz-tab-size:4;-o-tab-size:4;tab-size:4;line-height:1.15;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0;font-family:system-ui,-apple-system,Segoe UI,Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,Apple Color Emoji,Segoe UI Emoji}

.text-center { 
  text-align: center;
}
.font-bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just disable [Preflight](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#disabling-preflight)

```
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
  ....
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  }
}
```